# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. android studio

Tags: android, execution

I have downloaded a project from github and I'm trying to add some classes my own. When I add them I get this error:

> org.gradel.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   <29 internal calls>
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   Caused by: org.gradel.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Complilation failed; see the compiler error
>   output for details <11 internal calls>
>   at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:125) <12 internal calls>
>   ... 32 more

Any ideas why is this happening?Sorry if it's stupid but I'm new to this!

[image]

Comment: under java compiler expand that folder and check it for more details

Comment: Alex, I transcribed the error message from your image. Images of code are not easy to read on phones, nor are they searchable here on the site, and they are not accessible. By putting your code and error messages in the question as text you can make the question easier to answer and thus more likely to get at least one good answer. If I transcribed it correctly and there is no other important information in the image, please [edit] the question and remove the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have upgraded AS so you are not aware of new UI in latest ASv3.

You have clear errors inside `JavaCompiler > C/projects/social-app-android`

You have 5 errors, once you click that to expand you will be able to find the errors in classes.